# Import to NavEE?

Tags: categories, import, navigation, navee

I've got an existing site nav with well over 100 navigation elements in it (don't ask) as EE categories. Does anyone knows of a way to import a navigation hierarchy into NavEE, either directly from a category group, or indirectly via CSV or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

Not through any built-in method, no. But if you are familiar with writing SQL queries, I'm sure you could get the data out from the categories table, format it as needed, and re-insert it into the NavEE tables.

Comment: In thinking this through a bit more. Do you actually need to use NavEE here? Can you not just output the categories using the categories tag in the template?

Comment: Yeah, of course I can, and that's how I've _been_ doing nav so far. But the site is going to have a lot more people managing content in the backend soon, and I wanted to move away from the quirky nav-category method. 'Sides, NavEE makes mega-menus easier. :) As for your answer, I'm not familiar with the intricacies of NavEE's DB tables, and didn't want to just blindly mess with them.

Comment: Yeah, I use NavEE on just about every site, wasn't sure if the categories were just for a specific part of the site and were staying in use or not. Makes sense.

Comment: Nah, the categories are the way the nav has been done on the site for many years. Just wanted to bring things up to speed with NavEE. ;)